# SQL Mapping values of attributes with indexes

Tags: sql, database, relationships

Considering that I have the following 3 attributes:

```
WeatherCondition
 - rainy
 - sunny
 - cloudy

Daytime
 - day
 - night

RoadType
 - city
 - highway
 - underconstruction
```

And I want to map this values with indexes (day - 1, night - 2, etc..)

My question is, what way should I do this considering that anytime I would want to add 2-3 choices more to an attribute, or even new attributes?

Solution1:

```
AttributessTable:

ID  AttributeType   AttributeValue
AT1 WeatherCondition    rainy
AT2 WeatherCondition    sunny
AT3 Daytime             day
AT4 Daytime             night
AT5 WeatherCondition    cloudy
```

Solution2:
Separate tables for each attribute with only 2 columns (ID and value). WeatherCondition table with values (1,rainy; 2,sunny; 3,cloudy)
Daytime table with values (1,day; 2,night)

I'm somehow reluctant on the second solution thinking that I may have to create 30 tables.

The final result, is that I want to have a "lookup" or "bridge" table with the ID FK from another table like this:

```
FinalConditions 
ID  Attribute
1   AT1
1   AT3
1   AT5
2   AT2
2   AT5
```

Also, it's important to me to create reports by joining all this data altogether, I'm thinking that with Solution 2 it will be harder to join altogether 30 tables.

Comment: Clear advise: Solution 2. A well designed database consists of **many tables**. 30 tables is not *many*... My current project includes ~1000 tables...

Comment: I implemented by having for each attribute a table, holding only an ID as primary key and a Value as a string. My questions in, right now this tables are not linked to any other table, is that a problem? I mean I use them to map my values in a EAV table.

Comment: This is great... If you ever need additional columns later, you can just add them (kind of grouping key, costs for each item...) With a common table such later enhancements are very limited...

Comment: My only thinking is if I should add in those tables maybe another column for AttributeID and link them to Attribute table (AttributeID,AttributeValue) (used to hold all the attributes that a subject can hold) or leave it like this

Comment: I don't quite get this... You might start a new question with a  MCVE ([How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). In general: If you store a `m:n` relation via FK-columns in a mapping table, this is not an `EAV`-concept. `EAV` would mean to store a *table name*, an *attribute name* and a value (all as strings). Something which turns out as really, really bad in most cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it all comes down to scalability - how many rows are the tables expected to hold (all of them, summed up). If they're never going higher than say 10k, you shouldn't worry - Solution 1 will do.

However, if you expect the eventual number to be, say, in the millions of rows, Solution 2 is definitely the way to go - it'll lead to a lot less locks and it will probably be a lot easier to maintain (albeit harder to implement - you might have to "create 30 tables").

Hope this helps.